# How to change label color with html and CSS without js?

Tags: html, css

I am using checkbox type coding and I would like to make it so that for specific options, I am able to click it and it turns blue, and for other options, I can click it and it will turn red or green. I have found a way to do this, as shown in the CSS, but I figured I would have to keep writing code for each type of label. So I was wondering if there was a much more efficient way of doing this? Thanks. Here is the code:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
 display: none;
}

label {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #555;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
    background: blue;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label[for=red1] {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
    background: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label[for=red2] {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
    background: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label[for=green1] {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div><input id="blue1" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue1">1 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="blue2" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue2">2 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="blue3" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue3">3 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="blue4" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue4">4 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="red1" type="checkbox" /><label for="red1">1 red</label></div>
<div><input id="red2" type="checkbox" /><label for="red2">2 red</label></div>
<div><input id="green1" type="checkbox" /><label for="green1">1 green</label></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS ['starts with' attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (`^=`) to select all labels with a `for` attribute that starts with 'red', 'green', etc.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: blue;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label[for^=red] {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label[for^=green] {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
    label { color: red; }
    label span { color: green; }
```

```html
<label> Label <span>Text with other color</span> </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, you don't have to repeat the `color` and `font-weight` styles from the first `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label`.

An option would be to have classes for the different types of labels, for example:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .blue {
  background: blue;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .red {
  background: red;
}

...
```

Then your HTML:

```
<div><input id="blue1" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue1" class="blue">1 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="blue2" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue2" class="blue">2 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="blue3" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue3" class="blue">3 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="blue4" type="checkbox" /><label for="blue4" class="blue">4 blue</label></div>
<div><input id="red1" type="checkbox" /><label for="red1" class="red">1 red</label></div>
<div><input id="red2" type="checkbox" /><label for="red2" class="red">2 red</label></div>
<div><input id="green1" type="checkbox" /><label for="green1" class="green">1 green</label></div>
```

Further optimization would require some CSS preprocessor, such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html).

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  + label {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  + .blue {
    background: blue;
  }

  ...
}
```